# Update/change path to file in ms access field

Tags: ms-access

I have a database (form/query) with a field that has links to files so one can easily find and view those files. My organization has decided to do some housekeeping and unfortunately changed the path to those files. Can someone offer an easy example to update the field contents to the new path (preferably without VBA)?
Here is a simple description.

Fieldname1:

change

```
F:\oldpath\to\file\image1.tif
```

to

```
F:\newpath\to\file\image1.tif
```

If I need to create a new field that's fine. I can update my query/form to use the new field if necessary (that shouldn't be too hard).

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I made the problem way more complicated than necessary. All I had to do was use a simple find/replace from the command bar on the entire field.